# Creating image of plot and save on excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I created a code that groups data, creates a pivot table and saves it in the appropriate sheet.

```
    # dla każdej unikalnej nazwy w Kolumnie1
    for nazwa in unikalne_nazwy:
        # wyfiltruj wiersze z daną nazwą
        wyfiltrowane_dane = df_wynik_podsumowanie[df_wynik_podsumowanie['NAZWA'] == nazwa]
        wyfiltrowane_dane = wyfiltrowane_dane.pivot_table(values='SREDNIA_NORMA_OSIAGNIETA_srednia', index='P1_v2', columns='P2_v2', aggfunc='max', fill_value=0)
        df_suma = pivot.add(wyfiltrowane_dane, fill_value=0)
        df_suma = df_suma[new_order_col].loc[new_order_row]
    
    
        # zapisz wyfiltrowane dane do nowej zakładki w pliku Excel
        with pd.ExcelWriter('OEE_OKL_WYNIK.xlsx', engine='openpyxl' , mode='a') as writer:
            df_suma.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=nazwa)
```

I would like to generate a graph and paste it next to the generated table

`df_suma.plot()`

I would ask you for help

expects it to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax8vW.png)

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have that be an Excel chart, so it reacts to changes in the data?

Comment: I assumed that the data would be generated anew each time and the graph would be created during generation. I will not change the data after generation. But it can also be an excel chart, it doesn't have to be an image

Comment: Of course, it can be an excel chart, but I don't even know how to do it :(

Comment: Sorry, that was a distraction.  The pandas `ExcelWriter` has a limited single purpose.  You can use a package like `openpyxl` to create the Excel file yourself with more control.